# Given a set, find XOR of the XOR’s of all subsets

Tags: set, combinations, xor

I searched on net. The solution is at [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-set-find-xor-of-the-xors-of-all-subsets/).

The thing which I could not get was :

Let us consider n’th element, it can be included in all subsets of remaining (n-1) elements. The number of subsets for (n-1) elements is equal to 2^(n-1).

What is it trying to say?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jbrown How do we count the number of times an element of a set comes in subsets of the set ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. To count the number of times an element comes in the subsets of the set ... we fix the element and start counting number of subsets of length :

```
1 -> 1
2 ->NC1
3 ->NC2
.
.
.
N ->NC(N-1)
```

Total number of times an element appears in subsets of a given set = total number of subsets containing the element = 1 + NC1 + NC2 + NC3 + ..... + NC(N-1)
= 2^(N-1).